# Linux: immediate logoff upon login

Tags: centos, runlevel, logoff

I have a CentOS 6 installation (on a USB disk) that I use for repairs etc.  I recently moved the installation to a new disk, and now something strange is happening.  Immediately after I logon I am logged off.  I logon as root (no other user accounts).

In both runlevel 3 (console) and runlevel 5 (GUI) the same thing happens.  However, I can get into the system using runlevel 1.

Can someone suggest what might be going wrong, and how to fix this?

I tried running the individual and shared profile and bash scripts (once logged in under runlevel 1) and they work fine...I'm not logged out.

Out of ideas...

Comment: Anythimg relevant in your logs ?

Comment: Nope, but I just found the error: SELINUX.  I had to relabel/disable SELINUX and all is happy again.  I'll leave the question up in case someone else has this problem (seems like a simple answer but non obvious)

Comment: Please provide  proper answer then